# R - Return count of non N/A rows from multiple files depending on given value

Tags: r, dataframe

Note: All of the following is within R Studio Version 0.99.491

I'm trying to read a number of files (qty.50)
Within these files there are a numebr of NA values so I need to exclude these and only count the number of complete rows.

As I output the result I'd like to alter the column name and order too.

I think I've got the reading files bit sorted but it's the counting complete rows bit and changing headers that I'm struggling with.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

```
EXAMPLE DATA
1.csv
Date                Temp C  Rain mm SensorID
01/01/2016 12:00    26.0    0.0     1
02/01/2016 12:00    24.3    0.0     1
03/01/2016 12:00    N/A     3.1     1
04/01/2016 12:00    17.5    2.0     1
05/01/2016 12:00    15.8    N/A     1
06/01/2016 12:00    22.6    N/A     1

2.csv
Date                Temp C  Rain mm SensorID
01/01/2016 12:00    9.0     6.2     2
02/01/2016 12:00    7.3     1.0     2
03/01/2016 12:00    14.1    0.0     2
04/01/2016 12:00    12.4    0.2     2
05/01/2016 12:00    N/A     2.9     2
06/01/2016 12:00    N/A     N/A     2
```

My R function so far looks like this;

```
total_cases <- function(directory, id = 1:50) {
        files_list <- list.files("temperatures", full.names=TRUE)
        tempdf <- data.frame()
        for (i in 1:50) {
                tempdf <- rbind(tempdf, read.csv(files_list[i]))
        }
        tempdf_subset <- tempdf[which(!is.na(tempdf[, "ID"] %in% id),)]
        nrow(temp_subset)
}
```

so ideally I'd like to put one of the following queries and get a response as shown below:

```
total_cases("temperatures", 1)
      SensorID CountTemps 
[1]   1        3


total_cases("temperatures", 2)
      SensorID CountTemps
[1]   2        4


total_cases("temperatures", c(1,2)
      SensorID CountTemps
[1]   1        3
[1]   2        4
```

Many thanks for all spending time on this.
Matt

Comment: Did I phrase the question in the wrong way? 

I can get the read of files working, just not the output of it.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: I've got on a further few steps but still have an issue in the style of output. I've now reposed it with a clearer detail in http://stackoverflow.com/q/37464608/5913371